# how to use typesafe config library just render file content?

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I'm use `myConfig.root().render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise().setFormatted(true)))` print my config content.But I find it contains many other information, such as  `"version" : "2.4.16"`, `"stdout-loglevel" : "WARNING"`,etc, which is not defined in my config file.
Where is the info come from?
How can I just print my config file contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using Akka 2.4.16 (directly or indirectly), in which case the "extra" configuration settings are pulled from the [`reference.conf`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.16/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf), as described in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/configuration.html#Where_configuration_is_read_from). The `reference.conf` contains all the default configuration settings, and your `application.conf` can override any of those settings.

The `ActorSystem` merges the `reference.conf` with your `application.conf`, as seen [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.16/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L307). I don't think there is a way through the Typesafe Config API to render the contents of your `application.conf` without including the merged settings from `reference.conf`.

Comment: thanks. I realized `reference.conf` will be merged from other dependencies. I think the library should expose method to handle before merge and after merge config contents but it seems very complex.

Answer (score 1):

I use a way to render config with `parseResourcesAnySyntax` method by separate `myConfig` with `default`:

```
object DataServiceConfig {
  val local = ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("local")
  val online = ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("online")
  val develop = ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("application") //develop environment
  val default = ConfigFactory.load("application") //default environment

  val myConfig = local.withFallback(online).withFallback(develop)
  val combinedConfig = myConfig.withFallback(default)

  def printConf(config: Config): Unit = println(config.root().render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise().setFormatted(true).setJson(true)))


}
```

print config:  `DataServiceConfig.printConf(DataServiceConfig.myConfig)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `java.util.Properties` to just get your file contents, like this:

```
def getPropByFileName(fileName: String) = {
    val inputStream = this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
    val props = new Properties()
    props.load(inputStream)
    props
}
```